# How do I determine the superview of UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios7

I want to determine what view contains the image clicked on by the user in iOS 7.  Below is my layout.

```
+-------------------------------+
|  A                            |
| +---------------------------+ |
| |B                          | |
| |+--+                   +--+| |
| ||C | ------------------|D || |
| |+--+                   +--+| |
| |  |                      | | |
| |  |          G           | | |
| |  |                      | | |
| |+--+                   +--+| |
| ||E | ------------------|F || |
| |+--+                   +--+| |
| +---------------------------+ |
+-------------------------------+

Legend:
A - UIView
B - UIView subview of A
C, D, E, F - UIImageView subviews of B
G - UIImageView subview of A
```

I did a dump of the whole window hierarchy and it correctly shows C, D, E, F as subviews of B and B, G as a subviews of A.  This whole view hierarchy was built in IB and loaded as a XIB.

In the case the user tapped on the UIImageView C, I want to find out it's superview B.  However, when I do self.superview inside of the hittest for class C, it's always nil.

How do I determine the UIImageView (C, D, E, F) superview?

In case you're wondering, I'm trying to create grips (C, D, E, F) to manipulate the image in G.  I have multiple instances of A on the screen at a time and need to know which one is the superview of the grip that was tapped.

I'm missing some concept here and appreciate your tutelage.

**Update:** Here's the IB hierarchy of the views:

[image]

Here's the actual xib:

[image]

Here's the view dump at the class C hittest breakpoint:

```
UIWindow:<UIWindow: 0xb174590
| UILayoutContainerView:<UILayoutContainerView: 0xb17a7f0
| | UINavigationTransitionView:<UINavigationTransitionView: 0xb17c160
| | | UIViewControllerWrapperView:<UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0xb18f640
| | | | CanvasBackgroundView:<CanvasBackgroundView: 0xa63be10
| | | | | DragView:<DragView: 0xa6aec60
| | | | | | BorderView:<BorderView: 0xa6b92c0
| | | | | | | GripView:<GripView: 0xa6b2480
| | | | | | | GripView:<GripView: 0xa6bb020
| | | | | | | GripView:<GripView: 0xa6b29e0
| | | | | | | GripView:<GripView: 0xa6bb0d0
| | | | | | ContentImageView:<ContentImageView: 0xa6bb340
```

**@Timothy, all my hitTest methods are like this:**

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@ superview: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromClass([[self superview] class]));
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (self == hitView) {
        DDLogVerbose(@"hit for me: %@ %@ %@ self:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point), NSStringFromClass([hitView class]), NSStringFromCGRect(hitView.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
        return self; // we handled it
    } else {
        DDLogVerbose(@"hit not for me: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
        return nil; // not for us
    }
}
```

Comment: You said "inside of the hitTest for class C". How did you determine this. If you've subclassed `UIImageView` and overridden `hitTest`, please post the code for the class. `hitTest` wouldn't be called on a view that isn't in the hierarchy, so it's going to either have a superview or be the top-level view. My pet theory is you're looking at the `superview` of a local variable that's actually 'nil'.

Comment: @Timothy, I edited the post so I could get code formatting.  I'm actually logging [self superview] directly.  I've also set breakpoints in the hitTest and po showed it is nil.  BTW, I set break points in all hitTest methods and the superview is correct for all classes except the gripViews (C, D, E,F).  I've gone over the XIB over and over and can't see anything odd.  Like you said, hitTest is triggering so it's in the chain.

Comment: Is there anything else going on in `GripView` other than the overridden `hitTest` method, such as a custom initializer? Also, I'd override `addSubview` of `BorderView` with `[super addSubview:view]` and verify whether the incoming views are having their `superview` properties set after being added. Just for fun, try adding a regular `UIImageView` to `BorderView`.

Comment: @Timothy, thanks again for responding.  The whole UI is built with IB.  GripView class is nothing more than a subclass of UIImageView with the hitTest method.  This has got me baffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 UIView *iv = [imageView superView];
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since it should work.  I must have a reason it doesn't in my case.  I've now abandoned this approach.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

self.superview should do it. A hint - when you do 'po self' in the console, are you sure self is the imageView? Try assigning the ImageView's tag property, then while debugging, ensure that you're seeing the same tag. All UIViews have a tag property.

A sidenote, a view's superview if it is visible on the screen. Another hint - where/when are you throwing this breakpoint to stop execution? If it's somewhere in class C's init/build up methods, a superview may not be assigned yet. Make sure that you're querying the view after it's been presented on screen. You mention something about touch - call the BP after the tapGestureRecoginizer has been hit.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  As I said, my test was in hittest so everything is loaded.  self is defined as class C but self.superview is nil.  I'll modify my original question so you can see the IB hierarchy.

Comment: @Dan when you say "However, when I do self.superview inside of the hittest for class C, it's always nil." at what point in the execution are you throwing the BP and inspecting? Where are you seeing nil? Is it in an init method?

Comment: I set the breakpoint in the hitTest handler that is activated when I tap on the class C UIImageView.  [self superview] and self.superview return nil.

Comment: Is it possible it's related to the hitTest call chain?  Class A hitTest fires, does a super hitTest which fires Class B, does a super hitTest which fires C which then hits my break point

Comment: @Timothy, I didn't post code because it involves so many classes that it would be more confusing than helpful.  Thanks so much for responding.  I've now abandoned this approach since I couldn't find a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to your GripViews and call the delegate upon tap. Make sure you set userInteractionEnabled property to YES.

Comment: I already have userInteractionEnabled.  Can you explain why adding gesture recognizer to this class would change anything?  I don't have them on Class B but it's superview is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get the superview of a UIImageView from any other thread other than the main thread, it returns nil. Also, the center property will contain garbage values.